# get directory name replaced via * recursively

Tags: bash, shell

need help via bash

```
[edu@linux]$ tree test
test
├── 1dir
│      └── text.txt
├── 2dir
│      └── text.txt
└── 3dir
       └── text.txt

3 directories, 3 files


[edu@linux]$ cat test/*/text.txt
testtext1
testtext2
testtext3
```

how i can get output the name of dir masked via '*' in commandline
like this:

```
1dir testtext1
2dir testtext2
3dir testtext3
```

Thank you

Comment: Unless I am missing something, it is far simpler to use ls */text/txt | awk -F/  '{print $1,"test"$2}' . Adding a number to the end of each line is a also trivial operation with sed.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'FNR == 1 {split(FILENAME, parts, "/")}
     {print parts[2], $0}' test/*/test.txt
```

That is, on the first line of each file, split the filename on `/` into the `parts` array.

And for each line, print the second element of that array, and the full record (`$0`), separated with `OFS` (space by default).